# mootools checkboxes faster method

Tags: javascript, mootools, selector, each, checkbox

can I speed up this algorithm? The mootools javascript library used below?

```
var selected = '',
    slaves   = $$('input[name^="product[photos][attach][]"]');

slaves.addEvent("change", function () {
       selected = parseInt(this.get('value'));

       slaves.each(function(el){
          if (selected != parseInt(el.get('value'))) {
              el.getParent('div').addClass('hidden');
              el.checked = false;
          }
       });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is too slow?

Comment: I have a lot of checkboxes :)

Comment: And which part is slow? Selecting them, adding the event handlers, or hiding them?

Comment: provide example dom in jsfiddle. there are things to do here, for instance - not adding change events to all els is doable via event delegation (though it's a bit shit in IE6/7/(8?) due to no change event being fired, mootools normalizes this via propertychange instead). other things to do - don't look up the parents all the time but store them either the first time you access the element or on setup. also, the selector is going to be slow. try to use a className instead, if you can mod the dom tree

Comment: you can also build a lookup map based upon values so you can quickly anchor to the only slaves els you need to change

Comment: not tested but how about that : `slaves.addEvent("change", function () {
    selected = parseInt(this.get('value'));
    $$('input[name^="product[photos][attach][]"][value != "' + selected + '"]')
        .each(function (el) {
            if (selected != parseInt(el.get('value'))) {
                el.getParent('div').addClass('hidden');
                el.checked = false;
            }
        });
});` ? It would speed up a bit if there are only few checkboxes… Also @DimitarChristoff comment about adding a class would help I think, surely a fiddle could be helpful too ;)

Comment: this is worse imo, you are looking to the dom when the collection is in memory already. only algo that applies and will do instant updates is an values to elements map.

Comment: OP: in fact, how do you fire the change? if an element is hidden, it cannot be changed by user--hence, looks like it may be another event, in which case the whole thing can be simplified a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have that many checkboxes, or the number may vary, I would advise using relayed events (delegation) in mootools. I've had very good results on change, focus and blur events with that :

```
function onChange(_event, _input){
    //your code here
}
$(window).addEvent('change:relay(input[name^="product[photos][attach][]"])', onChange);
```

the doc for delegation can be found [here](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Delegation)

Comment: also, the Elements object returned by $$() can be filtered so you could do something like `$$('your predicate').filter(function(_item){return _item.get('value') != selected}).getPArents('div').addClass('hidden');`